# Work done in inducing emf across moving rod

Tags: electromagnetism, work

I saw a proof of the induced emf of a rod/wire moving perpendicular to a uniform magnetic field. My problem comes with the first step of the proof.

### Proof

Suppose we have a wire of length $l$. Consider one electron in the wire. The magnetic field does work on this electron to move it along the wire. The work done is given by: $$W=Fl$$ $$W=qvBl$$

Thus, $$ emf= \frac{W}{q}$$ $$emf=vBl$$

How can we say the total work done in moving all of the electrons to one end is $W=qvBl$ ? Before moving the wire through any magnetic fields the positive protons and negative electrons are "scattered" throughout the wire. Some electrons may already be positioned on the edge of the wire which they are being pushed to. Let's focus on one electron positioned a distance $d$ from the edge of the wire which the force will push it towards. Then the work done for this single electron would be $W_0=q_evBd$ and this could be repeated for all of the other electrons. So how can we be certain that the sum of all of these will equal $qvBl$.

### Edit

Proof provided by the textbook:
[image]

[image]

Comment: The work done is not $qvBl$ as magnetic fields don't produce any work directly. It is because a change of a magnetic field "produces" an electric field, which produces an emf. So, the formula $F=qvB$ can not be used to find emf. Apart from that, work is not $Fl$ being $l$ the length.

Comment: So it's merely a coincidence that it works out to the correct equation for the emf of a moving wire? This proof was straight out of one of my textbooks.

Comment: Can you find any source that you can send here?

Comment: Sure. I have updated the post with pictures from the textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is being described is a “steady state” condition.

An external agency exerts a force on the wire and the positive and negative charges within the wire are forced to move in the direction of the force.

You now have moving charges in a magnet field and thus a force is exerted on those charges at right angles to both the direction of motion of the wire and the magnetic field.

This force causes a motion of the free electrons in the wire, as the positive ions are bound to the lattice, which results in one end of the wire having a surplus of free electrons and the other end of the wire having a deficit of free electrons.
The imbalance in the charges along the length of the wire sets up an electric field which produces forces in opposition to the forces produced as a result of the free electrons moving in the magnetic field.
Eventually the two opposing forces have equal magnitudes and the movement of the free electrons ceases and an emf (potential difference) is set up.

The magnitude of the force due to the magnetic field $Bqv$ is equal to the force due the electric field $qE=q\frac {\Delta V}{l}$ which then gives you $\Delta V=Bvl$.

If you want to move a charge $q’$ between the two ends of the wire the work done is $q’\Delta V$ and this work would have to be done if the two ends of the wire were connected to a stationary conductor ie there is a current flowing in the complete conducting circuit.
The source of the work done is whatever is applying the force on the wire to make it move and thus producingan electric current.